# How to test if Ci successfully inserted data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Ci, I've got the following function. How do I test that the query successfully inserted without error's?

```
public function postToWall() {
    $entryData = $this->input->post('entryData');
    $myChurchId  = $this->session->userdata("myChurchId");
    $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO wallPosts (entryData, entryCreationDateTime, wpChurchId)
                      VALUES('$entryData', NOW(), '$myChurchId')");
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `$this->db->affected_rows()` function of codeigniter.

See more information [here](http://henrypeteralbers.com/user_guide/libraries/database/results.html)

You can do something like this:

```
return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
```

Comment: Or simply: `return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;`

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it using **Transactions** like this:

```
           $this->db->trans_start();
           $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO wallPosts (entryData, entryCreationDateTime, wpChurchId)
                      VALUES('$entryData', NOW(), '$myChurchId')");
           $this->db->trans_complete();

           if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
               return "Query Failed";
           } else {
               // do whatever you want to do on query success
           }
```

Here's [more info](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) on Transactions in CodeIgniter!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **bootstrap** on **codeigniter** try flash message
or
simply redirect

```
$added = $this->your_modal->function_reference($data);


if ($added) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Added successfully.');
    redirect('home');
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something wrong.');
    redirect('home');
```

**ON CONTROLLER**

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use

```
echo $this->db->affected_rows();
```

in models file

Answer (score 0):

**Codeigniter 4:**

```
    $db = db_connect();
     (your insert query)
    return ($db->affectedRows() != 1) ? false : true;
```